# How do I run an interpreter with command history support?

Tags: linux, bash, rlwrap, ledit

I know there is a way to run an interactive console with command history support (even though the program does not inherently support it). However, I don't remember the command. Can anyone help me?

Comment: You are probably thinking of rlwrap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install the package *rlwrap* and run it like

```
$ rlwrap foo
```

to get command line history for the command *foo*.

Answer (score 0):

Try `ledit`.

E.g.

```
$ ledit mycommand
```